# Data type handling in pandas apply() vs applymap()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types

I observed a different behavior in the handling of data types for the .apply() and the .applymap() functions of pandas.

```
big_number = 999999

big_number * big_number
Out[715]: 999998000001

np.square(big_number)
Out[716]: -729379967

np.square(float(big_number))
Out[717]: 999998000001.0

df = pd.DataFrame([big_number], columns=["big_number"])

df.dtypes
Out[719]: 
big_number    int64
dtype: object

df.apply(np.square)
Out[720]: 
     big_number
0  999998000001

df.applymap(np.square)
Out[721]: 
   big_number
0  -729379967

df.astype({"big_number" : float}).applymap(np.square)
Out[722]: 
     big_number
0  9.999980e+11
```

Obviously behaves .applymap() more correctly then .apply(), because it actually reproduces the result of the np.square() function. .apply() seems to do some magic data type conversion before calling the np.square function.

Can anybody explain what happens "under the hood"?

Comment: `apply` uses `pandas` internal method `frame_apply`.  Many internal methods have "smart" functions to infer result types. I don't have the `c` background to check this case, but I assume this is the culprit.  `applymap` generates a numpy array via `*.data` and applies the function to that, which is why the result is equivalent to `numpy`

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

*Everything boils down to **numpy** and **pandas** converting the built-in `int` type differently.*

Under the hood the `applymap` function applies `np.square` directly to dataframe entries, so it eventually passes through `np.square(big_number)`. Here `big_number` is converted by **numpy** to `np.int32` and the result is also 32-bit, so you get `-729379967`.

On the other hand, the `apply` function applies `np.square` to `df.values`. This is also a numpy's ndarray, but the tricky part is that while creating the DataFrame `big_number`'s value was first interpreted by **pandas** as 64-bit, hence `df.values.dtype` is  `np.int64` and not `np.int32`. Consequently, also the result is 64-bit and so it's `999998000001`.

### Additional example

You may observe the same behavior performing the following verification:

```
np_array = np.array(big_number)
np_array_2 = df.values
print(type(big_number), np_array.dtype, np_array_2.dtype)
print(np.square(np_array), np.square(np_array_2))
```

You should see the types are int, int32 and int64 and the results are `-729379967` and `[[999998000001]]`.

### Important

*Note that I was able to reproduce your problem only in numpy's 32-bit distribution, but not in the 64-bit one*. I guess the int conversion is governed by `np.int_`, which in the former environment coincides with `np.int32`, while in the latter one with `np.int64`.